# wildcard in FTP task SSIS package

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

I am trying to download a file from a FTP but has a timestamp. THe file format is YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.
How can I pull files just by the current day? Where would I add the wildcard

Answer (score 0):

This [link](http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.co.uk/2011/08/foreach-ftp-file-enumerator.html) should give a good start.

You will need to build current date as a string eg YYYYMMDD, this can be done using a script component or SQL task.

Pass the current date string value to a variable, using that variable using SSIS expression, compare the current day variable
with the first 8 characters of the current FTP file name, from the for each enumerator.